# How to get key name in asp net core 2.0 JwtBearer token from Azure AD

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, azure-active-directory

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web Api with authentication from Azure AD.

For authenticate against Azure AD I'm using Key instead of user credentials. Key is generated on Azure portal.

Is there any way to get name of used key inside of WebApi? I was not able to find him between Claims.

[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's just for decoration. What are you trying to do with the key? Perhaps there's a different way of getting what you want. Remember that those keys are still tied to the same user/client, so if you want to be able to differentiate between clients, you'll want to create a separate AzureAD application (and key) for each one so they have their own unique client/secret pair.

Comment: I have multiple Windows Services on premise. They are communicating with same App Service(web api). Each WS will have separated key and I would like to differentiate between them based on key. I thought that keys are not tied to any user. Just to AzureAD application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK , currently there is no such api will return the description of app key .In your scenario , you can't know which Windows Services based on your separated keys . As @jeffaudio suggested , you could create a separate AzureAD application (and key) for each Windows Services .

As a workaround ,  you could send a customize property when calling web api , the value of property will identify which service app sends the request , each app has separated value . You could include property in request header .